# How can I convert this apache user_agent blacklist regex into a php friendly regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, user-agent

I'm using this blacklist from http://perishablepress.com/blacklist/ua-2013.txt

If I strip out the regex and assign it to a php variable I get:

```
$strRegex = '\<|\>|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\!susie|\_irc|\_works|\+select\+|\+union\+|\&lt;\?|1\,\1\,1\,|3gse|4all|4anything|5\.1\;\ xv6875\)|59\.64\.153\.|85\.17\.|88\.0\.106\.|98|a\_browser|a1\ site|abac|abach|abby|aberja|abilon|abont|abot|accept|access|accoo|accoon|aceftp|acme|active|address|adopt|adress|advisor|agent|ahead|aihit|aipbot|alarm|albert|alek|alexa\ toolbar\;\ \(r1\ 1\.5\)|alltop|alma|alot|alpha|america\ online\ browser\ 1\.1|amfi|amfibi|anal|andit|anon|ansearch|answer|answerbus|answerchase|antivirx|apollo|appie|arach|archive|arian|aboutoil|asps|aster|atari|atlocal|atom|atrax|atrop|attrib|autoh|autohot|av\ fetch|avsearch|axod|axon|baboom|baby|back|baid|bali|bandit|barry|basichttp|batch|bdfetch|beat|beaut|become|bee|beij|betabot|biglotron|bilgi|binlar|bison|bitacle|bitly|blaiz|blitz|blogl|blogscope|blogzice|bloob|blow|bord|bond|boris|bost|bot\.ara|botje|botw|bpimage|brand|brok|broth|browseabit|browsex|bruin|bsalsa|bsdseek|built|bulls|bumble|bunny|busca|busi|buy|bwh3|cafek|cafi|camel|cand|captu|casper|catch|ccbot|ccubee|cd34|ceg|cfnetwork|cgichk|cha0s|chang|chaos|char|char\(|chase\ x|check\_http|checker|checkonly|checkprivacy|chek|chill|chttpclient|cipinet|cisco|cita|citeseer|clam|claria|claw|cloak|clshttp|clush|coast|cmsworldmap|code\.com|cogent|coldfusion|coll|collect|comb|combine|commentreader|common|comodo|compan|compatible\-|conc|conduc|contact|control|contype|conv|cool|copi|copy|coral|corn|cosmos|costa|cowbot|cr4nk|craft|cralwer|crank|crap|crawler0|crazy|cres|cs\-cz|cshttp|cuill|CURI|curl|curry|custo|cute|cyber|cz3|czx|daily|dalvik|daobot|dark|darwin|data|daten|dcbot|dcs|dds\ explorer|deep|deps|detect|dex|diam|diavol|diibot|dillo|ding|disc|disp|ditto|dlc|doco|dotbot|drag|drec|dsdl|dsok|dts|duck|dumb|eag|earn|earthcom|easydl|ebin|echo|edco|egoto|elnsb5|email|emer|empas|encyclo|enfi|enhan|enterprise\_search|envolk|erck|erocr|eventax|evere|evil|ewh|exac|exploit|expre|extra|eyen|fang|fast|fastbug|faxo|fdse|feed24|feeddisc|feedfinder|feedhub|fetch|filan|fileboo|fimap|find|firebat|firedownload\/1\.2pre\ firefox\/3\.6|firefox\/0|firs|flam|flash|flexum|flicky|flip|fly|focus|fooky|forum|forv|fost|foto|foun|fount|foxy\/1\;|free|friend|frontpage|fuck|fuer|futile|fyber|gais|galbot|gbpl|gecko\/2001|gecko\/2002|gecko\/2006|gecko\/2009042316|gener|geni|geo|geona|geth|getr|getw|ggl|gira|gluc|gnome|go\!zilla|goforit|goldfire|gonzo|google\ wireless|gosearch|got\-it|gozilla|grab|graf|greg|grub|grup|gsa\-cra|gsearch|gt\:\:www|guidebot|guruji|gyps|haha|hailo|harv|hash|hatena|hax|head|helm|herit|heritrix|hgre|hippo|hloader|hmse|hmview|holm|holy|hotbar\ 4\.4\.5\.0|hpprint|href\s|httpclient|httpconnect|httplib|httrack|human|huron|hverify|hybrid|hyper|ia_archiver|iaskspi|ibm\ evv|iccra|ichiro|icopy|ics\)|ida|ie\/5\.0|ieauto|iempt|iexplore\.exe|ilium|ilse|iltrov|indexer|indy|ineturl|infonav|innerpr|inspect|insuran|intellig|interget|internet\_explorer|internet\x|intraf|ip2|ipsel|irlbot|isc\_sys|isilo|isrccrawler|isspi|jady|jaka|jam|jenn|jet|jiro|jobo|joc|jupit|just|jyx|jyxo|kash|kazo|kbee|kenjin|kernel|keywo|kfsw|kkma|kmc|know|kosmix|krae|krug|ksibot|ktxn|kum|labs|lanshan|lapo|larbin|leech|lets|lexi|lexxe|libby|libcrawl|libcurl|libfetch|libweb|light|linc|lingue|linkcheck|linklint|linkman|lint|list|litefeeds|livedoor|livejournal|liveup|lmq|loader|locu|london|lone|loop|lork|lth\_|lwp|mac\_f|magi|magp|mail\.ru|main|majest|mam|mama|mana|marketwire|masc|mass|mata|mvi|mcbot|mecha|mechanize|mediapartners|metadata|metalogger|metaspin|metauri|mete|mib\/2\.2|microsoft\.url|microsoft\_internet\_explorer|mido|miggi|miix|mindjet|mindman|miner|mips|mira|mire|miss|mist|mizz|mj12|mlbot|mlm|mnog|moge|moje|mooz|more|mouse|mozdex|mozilla\/0|mozilla\/1|mozilla\/4\.61\ \[en\]|mozilla\/firefox|mpf|msie\ 2|msie\ 3|msie\ 4|msie\ 5|msie\ 6\.0\-|msie\ 6\.0b|msie\ 7\.0a1\;|msie\ 7\.0b\;|msie6xpv1|msiecrawler|msnbot\-media|msnbot\-products|msnptc|msproxy|msrbot|musc|mvac|mwm|my\_age|myapp|mydog|myeng|myie2|mysearch|myurl|nag|name|naver|navr|near|netants|netcach|netcrawl|netfront|netinfo|netmech|netsp|netx|netz|neural|neut|newsbreak|newsgatorinbox|newsrob|newt|next|ng\-s|ng\/2|nice|nikto|nimb|ninja|ninte|nog|noko|nomad|norb|note|npbot|nuse|nutch|nutex|nwsp|obje|ocel|octo|odi3|oegp|offby|offline|omea|omg|omhttp|onfo|onyx|openf|openssl|openu|opera\ 2|opera\ 3|opera\ 4|opera\ 5|opera\ 6|opera\ 7|orac|orbit|oreg|osis|our|outf|owl|p3p\_|page2rss|pagefet|pansci|parser|patw|pavu|pb2pb|pcbrow|pear|peer|pepe|perfect|perl|petit|phoenix\/0\.|phras|picalo|piff|pig|pingd|pipe|pirs|plag|planet|plant|platform|playstation|plesk|pluck|plukkie|poe\-com|poirot|pomp|post|postrank|powerset|preload|press|privoxy|probe|program\_shareware|protect|protocol|prowl|proxie|proxy|psbot|pubsub|puf|pulse|punit|purebot|purity|pyq|pyth|query|quest|qweer|radian|rambler|ramp|rapid|rawdog|rawgrunt|reap|reeder|refresh|reget|relevare|repo|requ|request|rese|retrieve|rip|rix|rma|roboz|rocket|rogue|rpt\-http|rsscache|ruby|ruff|rufus|rv\:0\.9\.7\)|salt|sample|sauger|savvy|sbcyds|sbider|sblog|sbp|scagent|scan|scej\_|sched|schizo|schlong|schmo|scorp|scott|scout|scrawl|screen|screenshot|script|seamonkey\/1\.5a|search17|searchbot|searchme|sega|semto|sensis|seop|seopro|sept|sezn|seznam|share|sharp|shaz|shell|shelo|sherl|shim|shopwiki|silurian|simple|simplepie|siph|sitekiosk|sitescan|sitevigil|sitex|skam|skimp|skygrid|sledink|sleip|slide|sly|smag|smurf|snag|snapbot|snapshot|snif|snip|snoop|sock|socsci|sogou|sohu|solr|some|soso|spad|span|spbot|speed|sphere|spin|sproose|spurl|sputnik|spyder|squi|sqwid|sqworm|ssm\_ag|stack|stamp|statbot|state|steel|stilo|strateg|stress|strip|style|subot|such|suck|sume|sunos\ 5\.7|sunrise|superbot|superbro|supervi|surf4me|surfbot|survey|susi|suza|suzu|sweep|swish|sygol|synapse|sync2it|systems|szukacz|tagger|tagoo|tagyu|take|talkro|tamu|tandem|tarantula|tbot|tcf|tcs\/1|teamsoft|tecomi|teesoft|teleport|telesoft|tencent|terrawiz|test|texnut|thomas|tiehttp|timebot|timely|tipp|tiscali|titan|tmcrawler|tmhtload|tocrawl|todobr|tongco|toolbar\;\ \(r1|topic|topyx|torrent|track|translate|traveler|treeview|tricus|trivia|trivial|true|tunnel|turing|turnitin|tutorgig|twat|tweak|twice|tygo|ubee|uchoo|ultraseek|unavail|unf|universal|unknown|upg1|urlbase|urllib|urly|user\-agent\:|useragent|usyd|vagabo|valet|vamp|vci|veri\~li|verif|versus|via|vikspider|virtual|visual|void|voyager|vsyn|w0000t|w3search|walhello|walker|wand|waol|watch|wavefire|wbdbot|weather|web\.ima|web2mal|webarchive|webbot|webcat|webcor|webcorp|webcrawl|webdat|webdup|webgo|webind|webis|webitpr|weblea|webmin|webmoney|webp|webql|webrobot|webster|websurf|webtre|webvac|webzip|wells|wep\_s|wget|whiz|widow|win67|windows\-rss|windows\ 2000|windows\ 3|windows\ 95|windows\ 98|windows\ ce|windows\ me|winht|winodws|wish|wizz|worio|works|world|worth|wwwc|wwwo|wwwster|xaldon|xbot|xenu|xirq|y\!tunnel|yacy|yahoo\-mmaudvid|yahooseeker|yahooysmcm|yamm|yand|yandex|yang|yoono|yori|yotta|yplus\ |ytunnel|zade|zagre|zeal|zebot|zerx|zeus|zhuaxia|zipcode|zixy|zmao|zmeu|zune|black\ hole|titan|webstripper|netmechanic|cherrypicker|emailcollector|emailsiphon|webbandit|emailwolf|extractorpro|copyrightcheck|crescent|wget|sitesnagger|prowebwalker|cheesebot|teleport|teleportpro|miixpc|telesoft|website\ quester|webzip|moget/2\.1|webzip/4\.0|websauger|webcopier|netants|mister\ pix|webauto|thenomad|www-collector-e|rma|libweb/clshttp|asterias|httplib|turingos|spanner|infonavirobot|harvest/1\.5|bullseye/1\.0|mozilla/4\.0\ \(compatible;\ bullseye;\ windows\ 95\)|crescent\ internet\ toolpak\ http\ ole\ control\ v\.1\.0|cherrypickerse/1\.0|cherrypicker\ /1\.0|webbandit/3\.50|nicerspro|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 5\.01\.4511|dittospyder|foobot|webmasterworldforumbot|spankbot|botalot|lwp-trivial/1\.34|lwp-trivial|wget/1\.6|bunnyslippers|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 6\.00\.8169|urly\ warning|wget/1\.5\.3|linkwalker|cosmos|moget|hloader|humanlinks|linkextractorpro|offline\ explorer|mata\ hari|lexibot|web\ image\ collector|the\ intraformant|true_robot/1\.0|true_robot|blowfish/1\.0|jennybot|miixpc/4\.2|builtbottough|propowerbot/2\.14|backdoorbot/1\.0|tocrawl/urldispatcher|webenhancer|tighttwatbot|suzuran|vci\ webviewer\ vci\ webviewer\ win32|vci|szukacz/1\.4|queryn\ metasearch|openfind\ data\ gathere|openfind|xenu\'s\ link\ sleuth\ 1\.1c|xenu\'s|zeus|repomonkey\ bait\ &\ tackle/v1\.01|repomonkey|zeus\ 32297\ webster\ pro\ v2\.9\ win32|webster\ pro|erocrawler|linkscan/8\.1a\ unix|keyword\ density/0\.9|kenjin\ spider|cegbfeieh';
```

I'd like to create a simple function like so:

```
function bot_detected($strUserAgent,$strRegex) {
    $pattern = '/' . $strRegex . '/i';
    if (isset($strUserAgent) && preg_match($pattern, $strUserAgent))
        return TRUE;
else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Some examples:

```
$arrUserAgents = array('Slurp','NING/1.0','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3');
foreach ($arrUserAgents as $strUserAgent) {
    if (bot_detected($strUserAgent)) {
        echo '<p>BOT: ' . $strUserAgent . '</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>NOT: ' . $strUserAgent . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

Here's a codepad if you'd like to help tinker: http://codepad.org/lF7apFKw

I've tried it out with several different regex strings to debug but can't put my finger on it.

```
$strRegex1 = '\<|\>|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\!susie|\_irc|\_works|\+select\+|\+union\+|\&lt;\?|1\,\1\,1\,|3gse|4all|4anything|5\.1\;\ xv6875\)|59\.64\.153\.|85\.17\.|88\.0\.106\.|98|a\_browser|a1\ site|abac|abach|abby|aberja|abilon|abont|abot|accept|access|accoo|accoon|aceftp|acme|active|address|adopt|adress|advisor|agent|ahead|aihit|aipbot|alarm|albert|alek|alexa\ toolbar\;\ \(r1\ 1\.5\)|alltop|alma|alot|alpha|america\ online\ browser\ 1\.1|amfi|amfibi|anal|andit|anon|ansearch|answer|answerbus|answerchase|antivirx|apollo|appie|arach|archive|arian|aboutoil|asps|aster|atari|atlocal|atom|atrax|atrop|attrib|autoh|autohot|av\ fetch|avsearch|axod|axon|baboom|baby|back|baid|bali|bandit|barry|basichttp|batch|bdfetch|beat|beaut|become|bee|beij|betabot|biglotron|bilgi|binlar|bison|bitacle|bitly|blaiz|blitz|blogl|blogscope|blogzice|bloob|blow|bord|bond|boris|bost|bot\.ara|botje|botw|bpimage|brand|brok|broth|browseabit|browsex|bruin|bsalsa|bsdseek|built|bulls|bumble|bunny|busca|busi|buy|bwh3|cafek|cafi|camel|cand|captu|casper|catch|ccbot|ccubee|cd34|ceg|cfnetwork|cgichk|cha0s|chang|chaos|char|char\(|chase\ x|check\_http|checker|checkonly|checkprivacy|chek|chill|chttpclient|cipinet|cisco|cita|citeseer|clam|claria|claw|cloak|clshttp|clush|coast|cmsworldmap|code\.com|cogent|coldfusion|coll|collect|comb|combine|commentreader|common|comodo|compan|compatible\-|conc|conduc|contact|control|contype|conv|cool|copi|copy|coral|corn|cosmos|costa|cowbot|cr4nk|craft|cralwer|crank|crap|crawler0|crazy|cres|cs\-cz|cshttp|cuill|CURI|curl|curry|custo|cute|cyber|cz3|czx|daily|dalvik|daobot|dark|darwin|data|daten|dcbot|dcs|dds\ explorer|deep|deps|detect|dex|diam|diavol|diibot|dillo|ding|disc|disp|ditto|dlc|doco|dotbot|drag|drec|dsdl|dsok|dts|duck|dumb|eag|earn|earthcom|easydl|ebin|echo|edco|egoto|elnsb5|email|emer|empas|encyclo|enfi|enhan|enterprise\_search|envolk|erck|erocr|eventax|evere|evil|ewh|exac|exploit|expre|extra|eyen|fang|fast|fastbug|faxo|fdse|feed24|feeddisc|feedfinder|feedhub|fetch|filan|fileboo|fimap|find|firebat|firedownload\/1\.2pre\ firefox\/3\.6|firefox\/0|firs|flam|flash|flexum|flicky|flip|fly|focus|fooky|forum|forv|fost|foto|foun|fount|foxy\/1\;|free|friend|frontpage|fuck|fuer|futile|fyber|gais|galbot|gbpl|gecko\/2001|gecko\/2002|gecko\/2006|gecko\/2009042316|gener|geni|geo|geona|geth|getr|getw|ggl|gira|gluc|gnome|go\!zilla|goforit|goldfire|gonzo|google\ wireless|gosearch|got\-it|gozilla|grab|graf|greg|grub|grup|gsa\-cra|gsearch|gt\:\:www|guidebot|guruji|gyps|haha|hailo|harv|hash|hatena|hax|head|helm|herit|heritrix|hgre|hippo|hloader|hmse|hmview|holm|holy|hotbar\ 4\.4\.5\.0|hpprint|href\s|httpclient|httpconnect|httplib|httrack|human|huron|hverify|hybrid|hyper|ia_archiver|iaskspi|ibm\ evv|iccra|ichiro|icopy|ics\)|ida|ie\/5\.0|ieauto|iempt|iexplore\.exe|ilium|ilse|iltrov|indexer|indy|ineturl|infonav|innerpr|inspect|insuran|intellig|interget|internet\_explorer|internet\x|intraf|ip2|ipsel|irlbot|isc\_sys|isilo|isrccrawler|isspi|jady|jaka|jam|jenn|jet|jiro|jobo|joc|jupit|just|jyx|jyxo|kash|kazo|kbee|kenjin|kernel|keywo|kfsw|kkma|kmc|know|kosmix|krae|krug|ksibot|ktxn|kum|labs|lanshan|lapo|larbin|leech|lets|lexi|lexxe|libby|libcrawl|libcurl|libfetch|libweb|light|linc|lingue|linkcheck|linklint|linkman|lint|list|litefeeds|livedoor|livejournal|liveup|lmq|loader|locu|london|lone|loop|lork|lth\_|lwp|mac\_f|magi|magp|mail\.ru|main|majest|mam|mama|mana|marketwire|masc|mass|mata|mvi|mcbot|mecha|mechanize|mediapartners|metadata|metalogger|metaspin|metauri|mete|mib\/2\.2|microsoft\.url|microsoft\_internet\_explorer|mido|miggi|miix|mindjet|mindman|miner|mips|mira|mire|miss|mist|mizz|mj12|mlbot|mlm|mnog|moge|moje|mooz|more|mouse|mozdex|mozilla\/0|mozilla\/1|mozilla\/4\.61\ \[en\]|mozilla\/firefox|mpf|msie\ 2|msie\ 3|msie\ 4|msie\ 5|msie\ 6\.0\-|msie\ 6\.0b|msie\ 7\.0a1\;|msie\ 7\.0b\;|msie6xpv1|msiecrawler|msnbot\-media|msnbot\-products|msnptc|msproxy|msrbot|musc|mvac|mwm|my\_age|myapp|mydog|myeng|myie2|mysearch|myurl|nag|name|naver|navr|near|netants|netcach|netcrawl|netfront|netinfo|netmech|netsp|netx|netz|neural|neut|newsbreak|newsgatorinbox|newsrob|newt|next|ng\-s|ng\/2|nice|nikto|nimb|ninja|ninte|nog|noko|nomad|norb|note|npbot|nuse|nutch|nutex|nwsp|obje|ocel|octo|odi3|oegp|offby|offline|omea|omg|omhttp|onfo|onyx|openf|openssl|openu|opera\ 2|opera\ 3|opera\ 4|opera\ 5|opera\ 6|opera\ 7|orac|orbit|oreg|osis|our|outf|owl|p3p\_|page2rss|pagefet|pansci|parser|patw|pavu|pb2pb|pcbrow|pear|peer|pepe|perfect|perl|petit|phoenix\/0\.|phras|picalo|piff|pig|pingd|pipe|pirs|plag|planet|plant|platform|playstation|plesk|pluck|plukkie|poe\-com|poirot|pomp|post|postrank|powerset|preload|press|privoxy|probe|program\_shareware|protect|protocol|prowl|proxie|proxy|psbot|pubsub|puf|pulse|punit|purebot|purity|pyq|pyth|query|quest|qweer|radian|rambler|ramp|rapid|rawdog|rawgrunt|reap|reeder|refresh|reget|relevare|repo|requ|request|rese|retrieve|rip|rix|rma|roboz|rocket|rogue|rpt\-http|rsscache|ruby|ruff|rufus|rv\:0\.9\.7\)|salt|sample|sauger|savvy|sbcyds|sbider|sblog|sbp|scagent|scan|scej\_|sched|schizo|schlong|schmo|scorp|scott|scout|scrawl|screen|screenshot|script|seamonkey\/1\.5a|search17|searchbot|searchme|sega|semto|sensis|seop|seopro|sept|sezn|seznam|share|sharp|shaz|shell|shelo|sherl|shim|shopwiki|silurian|simple|simplepie|siph|sitekiosk|sitescan|sitevigil|sitex|skam|skimp|skygrid|sledink|sleip|slide|sly|smag|smurf|snag|snapbot|snapshot|snif|snip|snoop|sock|socsci|sogou|sohu|solr|some|soso|spad|span|spbot|speed|sphere|spin|sproose|spurl|sputnik|spyder|squi|sqwid|sqworm|ssm\_ag|stack|stamp|statbot|state|steel|stilo|strateg|stress|strip|style|subot|such|suck|sume|sunos\ 5\.7|sunrise|superbot|superbro|supervi|surf4me|surfbot|survey|susi|suza|suzu|sweep|swish|sygol|synapse|sync2it|systems|szukacz|tagger|tagoo|tagyu|take|talkro|tamu|tandem|tarantula|tbot|tcf|tcs\/1|teamsoft|tecomi|teesoft|teleport|telesoft|tencent|terrawiz|test|texnut|thomas|tiehttp|timebot|timely|tipp|tiscali|titan|tmcrawler|tmhtload|tocrawl|todobr|tongco|toolbar\;\ \(r1|topic|topyx|torrent|track|translate|traveler|treeview|tricus|trivia|trivial|true|tunnel|turing|turnitin|tutorgig|twat|tweak|twice|tygo|ubee|uchoo|ultraseek|unavail|unf|universal|unknown|upg1|urlbase|urllib|urly|user\-agent\:|useragent|usyd|vagabo|valet|vamp|vci|veri\~li|verif|versus|via|vikspider|virtual|visual|void|voyager|vsyn|w0000t|w3search|walhello|walker|wand|waol|watch|wavefire|wbdbot|weather|web\.ima|web2mal|webarchive|webbot|webcat|webcor|webcorp|webcrawl|webdat|webdup|webgo|webind|webis|webitpr|weblea|webmin|webmoney|webp|webql|webrobot|webster|websurf|webtre|webvac|webzip|wells|wep\_s|wget|whiz|widow|win67|windows\-rss|windows\ 2000|windows\ 3|windows\ 95|windows\ 98|windows\ ce|windows\ me|winht|winodws|wish|wizz|worio|works|world|worth|wwwc|wwwo|wwwster|xaldon|xbot|xenu|xirq|y\!tunnel|yacy|yahoo\-mmaudvid|yahooseeker|yahooysmcm|yamm|yand|yandex|yang|yoono|yori|yotta|yplus\ |ytunnel|zade|zagre|zeal|zebot|zerx|zeus|zhuaxia|zipcode|zixy|zmao|zmeu|zune|black\ hole|titan|webstripper|netmechanic|cherrypicker|emailcollector|emailsiphon|webbandit|emailwolf|extractorpro|copyrightcheck|crescent|wget|sitesnagger|prowebwalker|cheesebot|teleport|teleportpro|miixpc|telesoft|website\ quester|webzip|moget/2\.1|webzip/4\.0|websauger|webcopier|netants|mister\ pix|webauto|thenomad|www-collector-e|rma|libweb/clshttp|asterias|httplib|turingos|spanner|infonavirobot|harvest/1\.5|bullseye/1\.0|mozilla/4\.0\ \(compatible;\ bullseye;\ windows\ 95\)|crescent\ internet\ toolpak\ http\ ole\ control\ v\.1\.0|cherrypickerse/1\.0|cherrypicker\ /1\.0|webbandit/3\.50|nicerspro|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 5\.01\.4511|dittospyder|foobot|webmasterworldforumbot|spankbot|botalot|lwp-trivial/1\.34|lwp-trivial|wget/1\.6|bunnyslippers|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 6\.00\.8169|urly\ warning|wget/1\.5\.3|linkwalker|cosmos|moget|hloader|humanlinks|linkextractorpro|offline\ explorer|mata\ hari|lexibot|web\ image\ collector|the\ intraformant|true_robot/1\.0|true_robot|blowfish/1\.0|jennybot|miixpc/4\.2|builtbottough|propowerbot/2\.14|backdoorbot/1\.0|tocrawl/urldispatcher|webenhancer|tighttwatbot|suzuran|vci\ webviewer\ vci\ webviewer\ win32|vci|szukacz/1\.4|queryn\ metasearch|openfind\ data\ gathere|openfind|xenu\'s\ link\ sleuth\ 1\.1c|xenu\'s|zeus|repomonkey\ bait\ &\ tackle/v1\.01|repomonkey|zeus\ 32297\ webster\ pro\ v2\.9\ win32|webster\ pro|erocrawler|linkscan/8\.1a\ unix|keyword\ density/0\.9|kenjin\ spider|cegbfeieh';
$strRegex2 = '\Slurp|bingbot\i';
$strRegex3 = '\<|\>|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\+select|\+union|\&lt|binlar|casper|checkprivacy|cmsworldmap|comodo|curious|diavol|doco|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|libwww|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|msnbot|NING|turnit|vikspid|zmeu|zune|robot|spider|crawler|curl';

function bot_detected($strUserAgent,$strRegex) {
    $pattern = '/' . $strRegex . '/i';
    if (isset($strUserAgent) && preg_match($pattern, $strUserAgent))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

$arrUserAgents = array('Slurp','NING/1.0','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3');
foreach ($arrUserAgents as $strUserAgent) {
    if (bot_detected($strUserAgent,$strRegex3))
        echo "BOT: $strUserAgent\n";
    else
        echo "NOT: $strUserAgent\n";
}
```

Can you help me figure out what's stopping the main regex (`$strRegex1` above) from working?

Here's one example error:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '2' in script.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '2' in script.php on line 27
```

My hunch is there are unescaped characters in the string above.  But I can't figure it out.

Comment: Pick another delimiter if `/` is already used in the regex.

Comment: Thanks @mario, and HamZa. Absolutely on target.

Comment: Your regex contains `\1`, which has special meaning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `$strRegex1` thinks it should be looking for a subpattern, based on the first `<` occurence.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
$strRegex1 = '[<]|(\>)|\'|\$x0E|\%0A|\%0D|\%27|\%3C|\%3E|\%00|\@\$x|\!susie|\_irc|\_works|\+select\+|\+union\+|\&lt;\?|1\,\1\,1\,|3gse|4all|4anything|5\.1\;\ xv6875\)|59\.64\.153\.|85\.17\.|88\.0\.106\.|98|a\_browser|a1\ site|abac|abach|abby|aberja|abilon|abont|abot|accept|access|accoo|accoon|aceftp|acme|active|address|adopt|adress|advisor|agent|ahead|aihit|aipbot|alarm|albert|alek|alexa\ toolbar\;\ \(r1\ 1\.5\)|alltop|alma|alot|alpha|america\ online\ browser\ 1\.1|amfi|amfibi|anal|andit|anon|ansearch|answer|answerbus|answerchase|antivirx|apollo|appie|arach|archive|arian|aboutoil|asps|aster|atari|atlocal|atom|atrax|atrop|attrib|autoh|autohot|av\ fetch|avsearch|axod|axon|baboom|baby|back|baid|bali|bandit|barry|basichttp|batch|bdfetch|beat|beaut|become|bee|beij|betabot|biglotron|bilgi|binlar|bison|bitacle|bitly|blaiz|blitz|blogl|blogscope|blogzice|bloob|blow|bord|bond|boris|bost|bot\.ara|botje|botw|bpimage|brand|brok|broth|browseabit|browsex|bruin|bsalsa|bsdseek|built|bulls|bumble|bunny|busca|busi|buy|bwh3|cafek|cafi|camel|cand|captu|casper|catch|ccbot|ccubee|cd34|ceg|cfnetwork|cgichk|cha0s|chang|chaos|char|char\(|chase\ x|check\_http|checker|checkonly|checkprivacy|chek|chill|chttpclient|cipinet|cisco|cita|citeseer|clam|claria|claw|cloak|clshttp|clush|coast|cmsworldmap|code\.com|cogent|coldfusion|coll|collect|comb|combine|commentreader|common|comodo|compan|compatible\-|conc|conduc|contact|control|contype|conv|cool|copi|copy|coral|corn|cosmos|costa|cowbot|cr4nk|craft|cralwer|crank|crap|crawler0|crazy|cres|cs\-cz|cshttp|cuill|CURI|curl|curry|custo|cute|cyber|cz3|czx|daily|dalvik|daobot|dark|darwin|data|daten|dcbot|dcs|dds\ explorer|deep|deps|detect|dex|diam|diavol|diibot|dillo|ding|disc|disp|ditto|dlc|doco|dotbot|drag|drec|dsdl|dsok|dts|duck|dumb|eag|earn|earthcom|easydl|ebin|echo|edco|egoto|elnsb5|email|emer|empas|encyclo|enfi|enhan|enterprise\_search|envolk|erck|erocr|eventax|evere|evil|ewh|exac|exploit|expre|extra|eyen|fang|fast|fastbug|faxo|fdse|feed24|feeddisc|feedfinder|feedhub|fetch|filan|fileboo|fimap|find|firebat|firedownload\/1\.2pre\ firefox\/3\.6|firefox\/0|firs|flam|flash|flexum|flicky|flip|fly|focus|fooky|forum|forv|fost|foto|foun|fount|foxy\/1\;|free|friend|frontpage|fuck|fuer|futile|fyber|gais|galbot|gbpl|gecko\/2001|gecko\/2002|gecko\/2006|gecko\/2009042316|gener|geni|geo|geona|geth|getr|getw|ggl|gira|gluc|gnome|go\!zilla|goforit|goldfire|gonzo|google\ wireless|gosearch|got\-it|gozilla|grab|graf|greg|grub|grup|gsa\-cra|gsearch|gt\:\:www|guidebot|guruji|gyps|haha|hailo|harv|hash|hatena|hax|head|helm|herit|heritrix|hgre|hippo|hloader|hmse|hmview|holm|holy|hotbar\ 4\.4\.5\.0|hpprint|href\s|httpclient|httpconnect|httplib|httrack|human|huron|hverify|hybrid|hyper|ia_archiver|iaskspi|ibm\ evv|iccra|ichiro|icopy|ics\)|ida|ie\/5\.0|ieauto|iempt|iexplore\.exe|ilium|ilse|iltrov|indexer|indy|ineturl|infonav|innerpr|inspect|insuran|intellig|interget|internet\_explorer|internet\x|intraf|ip2|ipsel|irlbot|isc\_sys|isilo|isrccrawler|isspi|jady|jaka|jam|jenn|jet|jiro|jobo|joc|jupit|just|jyx|jyxo|kash|kazo|kbee|kenjin|kernel|keywo|kfsw|kkma|kmc|know|kosmix|krae|krug|ksibot|ktxn|kum|labs|lanshan|lapo|larbin|leech|lets|lexi|lexxe|libby|libcrawl|libcurl|libfetch|libweb|light|linc|lingue|linkcheck|linklint|linkman|lint|list|litefeeds|livedoor|livejournal|liveup|lmq|loader|locu|london|lone|loop|lork|lth\_|lwp|mac\_f|magi|magp|mail\.ru|main|majest|mam|mama|mana|marketwire|masc|mass|mata|mvi|mcbot|mecha|mechanize|mediapartners|metadata|metalogger|metaspin|metauri|mete|mib\/2\.2|microsoft\.url|microsoft\_internet\_explorer|mido|miggi|miix|mindjet|mindman|miner|mips|mira|mire|miss|mist|mizz|mj12|mlbot|mlm|mnog|moge|moje|mooz|more|mouse|mozdex|mozilla\/0|mozilla\/1|mozilla\/4\.61\ \[en\]|mozilla\/firefox|mpf|msie\ 2|msie\ 3|msie\ 4|msie\ 5|msie\ 6\.0\-|msie\ 6\.0b|msie\ 7\.0a1\;|msie\ 7\.0b\;|msie6xpv1|msiecrawler|msnbot\-media|msnbot\-products|msnptc|msproxy|msrbot|musc|mvac|mwm|my\_age|myapp|mydog|myeng|myie2|mysearch|myurl|nag|name|naver|navr|near|netants|netcach|netcrawl|netfront|netinfo|netmech|netsp|netx|netz|neural|neut|newsbreak|newsgatorinbox|newsrob|newt|next|ng\-s|ng\/2|nice|nikto|nimb|ninja|ninte|nog|noko|nomad|norb|note|npbot|nuse|nutch|nutex|nwsp|obje|ocel|octo|odi3|oegp|offby|offline|omea|omg|omhttp|onfo|onyx|openf|openssl|openu|opera\ 2|opera\ 3|opera\ 4|opera\ 5|opera\ 6|opera\ 7|orac|orbit|oreg|osis|our|outf|owl|p3p\_|page2rss|pagefet|pansci|parser|patw|pavu|pb2pb|pcbrow|pear|peer|pepe|perfect|perl|petit|phoenix\/0\.|phras|picalo|piff|pig|pingd|pipe|pirs|plag|planet|plant|platform|playstation|plesk|pluck|plukkie|poe\-com|poirot|pomp|post|postrank|powerset|preload|press|privoxy|probe|program\_shareware|protect|protocol|prowl|proxie|proxy|psbot|pubsub|puf|pulse|punit|purebot|purity|pyq|pyth|query|quest|qweer|radian|rambler|ramp|rapid|rawdog|rawgrunt|reap|reeder|refresh|reget|relevare|repo|requ|request|rese|retrieve|rip|rix|rma|roboz|rocket|rogue|rpt\-http|rsscache|ruby|ruff|rufus|rv\:0\.9\.7\)|salt|sample|sauger|savvy|sbcyds|sbider|sblog|sbp|scagent|scan|scej\_|sched|schizo|schlong|schmo|scorp|scott|scout|scrawl|screen|screenshot|script|seamonkey\/1\.5a|search17|searchbot|searchme|sega|semto|sensis|seop|seopro|sept|sezn|seznam|share|sharp|shaz|shell|shelo|sherl|shim|shopwiki|silurian|simple|simplepie|siph|sitekiosk|sitescan|sitevigil|sitex|skam|skimp|skygrid|sledink|sleip|slide|sly|smag|smurf|snag|snapbot|snapshot|snif|snip|snoop|sock|socsci|sogou|sohu|solr|some|soso|spad|span|spbot|speed|sphere|spin|sproose|spurl|sputnik|spyder|squi|sqwid|sqworm|ssm\_ag|stack|stamp|statbot|state|steel|stilo|strateg|stress|strip|style|subot|such|suck|sume|sunos\ 5\.7|sunrise|superbot|superbro|supervi|surf4me|surfbot|survey|susi|suza|suzu|sweep|swish|sygol|synapse|sync2it|systems|szukacz|tagger|tagoo|tagyu|take|talkro|tamu|tandem|tarantula|tbot|tcf|tcs\/1|teamsoft|tecomi|teesoft|teleport|telesoft|tencent|terrawiz|test|texnut|thomas|tiehttp|timebot|timely|tipp|tiscali|titan|tmcrawler|tmhtload|tocrawl|todobr|tongco|toolbar\;\ \(r1|topic|topyx|torrent|track|translate|traveler|treeview|tricus|trivia|trivial|true|tunnel|turing|turnitin|tutorgig|twat|tweak|twice|tygo|ubee|uchoo|ultraseek|unavail|unf|universal|unknown|upg1|urlbase|urllib|urly|user\-agent\:|useragent|usyd|vagabo|valet|vamp|vci|veri\~li|verif|versus|via|vikspider|virtual|visual|void|voyager|vsyn|w0000t|w3search|walhello|walker|wand|waol|watch|wavefire|wbdbot|weather|web\.ima|web2mal|webarchive|webbot|webcat|webcor|webcorp|webcrawl|webdat|webdup|webgo|webind|webis|webitpr|weblea|webmin|webmoney|webp|webql|webrobot|webster|websurf|webtre|webvac|webzip|wells|wep\_s|wget|whiz|widow|win67|windows\-rss|windows\ 2000|windows\ 3|windows\ 95|windows\ 98|windows\ ce|windows\ me|winht|winodws|wish|wizz|worio|works|world|worth|wwwc|wwwo|wwwster|xaldon|xbot|xenu|xirq|y\!tunnel|yacy|yahoo\-mmaudvid|yahooseeker|yahooysmcm|yamm|yand|yandex|yang|yoono|yori|yotta|yplus\ |ytunnel|zade|zagre|zeal|zebot|zerx|zeus|zhuaxia|zipcode|zixy|zmao|zmeu|zune|black\ hole|titan|webstripper|netmechanic|cherrypicker|emailcollector|emailsiphon|webbandit|emailwolf|extractorpro|copyrightcheck|crescent|wget|sitesnagger|prowebwalker|cheesebot|teleport|teleportpro|miixpc|telesoft|website\ quester|webzip|moget/2\.1|webzip/4\.0|websauger|webcopier|netants|mister\ pix|webauto|thenomad|www-collector-e|rma|libweb/clshttp|asterias|httplib|turingos|spanner|infonavirobot|harvest/1\.5|bullseye/1\.0|mozilla/4\.0\ \(compatible;\ bullseye;\ windows\ 95\)|crescent\ internet\ toolpak\ http\ ole\ control\ v\.1\.0|cherrypickerse/1\.0|cherrypicker\ /1\.0|webbandit/3\.50|nicerspro|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 5\.01\.4511|dittospyder|foobot|webmasterworldforumbot|spankbot|botalot|lwp-trivial/1\.34|lwp-trivial|wget/1\.6|bunnyslippers|microsoft\ url\ control\ -\ 6\.00\.8169|urly\ warning|wget/1\.5\.3|linkwalker|cosmos|moget|hloader|humanlinks|linkextractorpro|offline\ explorer|mata\ hari|lexibot|web\ image\ collector|the\ intraformant|true_robot/1\.0|true_robot|blowfish/1\.0|jennybot|miixpc/4\.2|builtbottough|propowerbot/2\.14|backdoorbot/1\.0|tocrawl/urldispatcher|webenhancer|tighttwatbot|suzuran|vci\ webviewer\ vci\ webviewer\ win32|vci|szukacz/1\.4|queryn\ metasearch|openfind\ data\ gathere|openfind|xenu\'s\ link\ sleuth\ 1\.1c|xenu\'s|zeus|repomonkey\ bait\ &\ tackle/v1\.01|repomonkey|zeus\ 32297\ webster\ pro\ v2\.9\ win32|webster\ pro|erocrawler|linkscan/8\.1a\ unix|keyword\ density/0\.9|kenjin\ spider|cegbfeieh';
```

And then modifying `bot_detected()` so it uses a different delimiter, such as `~`:

```
function bot_detected($strUserAgent,$strRegex) {
    $pattern = '~' . $strRegex . '~i';
    if (isset($strUserAgent) && preg_match($pattern, $strUserAgent))
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

I noticed that `$strRegex1` does not look for *Slurp* or *Ning* like the other ones, though... Not sure if that was intentional or not but if not you can add either or both of them somewhere in the middle (obviously).

Either way, after those modifications the following seems to work with no problems:

```
$arrUserAgents = array('Slurp','NING/1.0','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3');
foreach ($arrUserAgents as $strUserAgent) {
    if (bot_detected($strUserAgent,$strRegex1))
        echo "BOT: $strUserAgent\n";
    else
        echo "NOT: $strUserAgent\n";
}
```